# angular ui router resets the toState.name after redirect

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My user can change a date in the url bar.

The logic for the url change is in my app.js => stateChangeStart function =>

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'plannerFactory',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, plannerFactory) {

      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.name === "main.projects.selected.dates.day") {

          ev.preventDefault();

// code here removed for brevity...

     var dateString = toParams.year + " " + toParams.month + " " + toParams.day;
                var newDate = moment(dateString, "YYYY MM DD");
                if (newDate.isValid()) {
                  plannerFactory.day = newDate.subtract(1, 'months');
                }
                else {
                  toState.name = "main.projects";
                  // When this is done and I am on the main.projectsstate I want to return HERE again entering a correct date to execute
                  // the above code where the date is valid BUT before I get here again I do the $state.go(...) which always worked but NOW
                  // the toState.name has STILL the old main.projects, I assumed the $state.go which I do would change the toState.name not?
                  // That would make sense...
                }

    // This prevents infinite loop/recursion
              $state.go(toState.name, toParams, { notify: false }).then(function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams);
              });

   }
}
```

When the url change does not result in a valid date I want to redirect the user to the main.projects site which is my landing/start page.

When I got redirected to the main.projects state I click a button which triggers a $state.go('main.projects.whatever');

Thats the state.go in the 'projectsController' where I open a project via:

```
$scope.open = function () {
    plannerFactory.day = moment();
    $state.go("main.projects.selected.dates.day", { id: $state.params.id }, {reload: true}); 
  };
```

After triggering the open project button Then the stateChangeStart is triggered and when I examine the toState.name I can read the value 'main.projects' but actually it would be logically to me that the toState.name is 'main.projects.whatever'. As this is not the case I never reach my target instead I have kind of recursion/revert behavior.

I can never leave the main.projects state.

Is this a bug or what do I wrong?

UPDATE

Comment: I'm confused with your question. I don't understand it properly. Why don't you show us your routing code? N what newDate.isValid() is?

Comment: attach fiddle please.

Comment: I have put more code, sorry guys!

Comment: @micronyks Why is the newDate.isValid() interesting for you? Its my business logic and not part of the question here.

Comment: I still confused with what  you are looking for, I mean  I'm not clear with it. Still try one thing, take  your $rootScope.$on code out side of .run method. and inject required factory there into $rootScope.$on.